# Is there any limit for flow Paused and Waiting interview?

Tags: process-builder, flow, schedule

I scheduled emails for 100 days before in Process builder. Now If i schedule individually 10000 emails actions, will they fire or not?

Here i can see 10 paused interviews, so How many can process and how may we can see.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From SFDC [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits.htm&language=en_US)

> **1000**  - Maximum number of flow interviews that are resumed or groups of scheduled actions that are executed per hour.
>
> **30,000** - Maximum number of flow interviews or groups of scheduled actions (from processes) that are waiting at one time.

In the browser I believe you can see all which are pending provided that the browser does not crashes. I have not tried this.